# Modify (potentially) many URLs within an HTML document in C++

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I'm given a string which contains the contents of an HTML document, and I need to modify some of the URLs contained within the document. The URLs which need modification begin with the form:

`<script src="https://foo.com/some/variable/path/to/file.js" ...`

And must be modified to:

`<script src="https://foo.com/some/variable/path/to/NEW/file.js" ...`

My current approach has been to use [Google's RE2](https://github.com/google/re2)'s GlobalReplace function with the regexp:

`"(?i)(<script\\s+(?:[^>]+\\s+)?src=[\"']https://foo\\.com/"
    "(?:.*?/)*?)(.*?\\.js[\"'][^>]*>)"`

Which almost works, until I realized that it's possible that the HTML that I'm given might already have some of the URLs *modified* and some not, the former of which should be left alone.

**Question**: What's the easiest way to go about modifying the URLs without modifying the ones that have already been modified upstream?

A single pass approach is essential.

Comment: Write a regex that doesn't match the new ones.  Since you're obfuscating them we can't help you do it.  But at least we don't know the general  organization of your site's files ( heaven forbid ) :P

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean to write a regex that doesn't match the form of the modified URL? If so, I've considered that, but I'm not actually sure how that would help.

Comment: Then you can do a standard regex replace process and voila, only the broken urls are fixed, and since the new ones don't match, they won't be replaced.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm wrong or misunderstanding, but I don't think that would work. The document I'm given can have any number of such script tags, some of which may need modifications, and some of which may already be modified. I need to be able to modify the ones that have not yet been modified, and to leave the already modified ones alone.

Comment: I realized my original post did not make that clear, so I've gone ahead and edited it.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word .